# SQL - Delimiting to a Specific Range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM `cpus_z-series` WHERE `Model_ID` LIKE '%Z5%';
```

The above SQL query would target both 500 and 5000 series. I want to know if there's a way to delimit this further to select only 500 or only 5000 series models. No matter how many percentage signs I add to the end, the same happens.

I'm assuming this might be possible using RegEx, but I'm not that great with regular expressions.

#### **Edit:**

I forgot to mention that the model numbers overlap. For example, Z550 exists, but so does Z5500. And furthermore, there are model numbers with awkward endings, like Z552 and Z5505.

Comment: `WHERE Model_ID = 'Z500'`?

Comment: @juergend I wish it was that simple. The model numbers vary and overlap. For example, Z550 exists, but so does Z5500. And some have odd endings (Z552 and Z5505).

Comment: use `underscore` to give exact number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why do you have the wildcard at the front?  Wouldn't this do the same thing?

```
WHERE `Model_ID` LIKE 'Z5%';
```

If so, you can just use the length of the string:

```
WHERE `Model_ID` LIKE 'Z5%' AND LENGTH(Model_ID) = 4
```

Of course, you can also use regular expressions.  However, the advantage of using this method is that it can actually take advantage of an index on `Model_Id`, because the `LIKE` pattern starts with a fixed character.

Also, you can use `_` to represent any single character in `like`:

```
WHERE `Model_ID` LIKE 'Z5__'
```

This is probably closest to what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Gordon. It was at the front because I was trying to get to grips with the way SQL managed searching, and in phpMyAdmin, the `LIKE %...%` appeared to work at first. Now with the overlapping of the models, it's stopped functioning. I'm fairly new to SQL. Thank you for the various methods. :)

Comment: For reference, the last method you described with underscores, seems to be the closest to my needs. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To select only 5xx models

```
SELECT * 
FROM `cpus_z-series` 
WHERE `Model_ID` REGEXP '^Z5[0-9]{2}$'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can limit it using `_` underscore

```
SELECT * FROM cpus_z-series WHERE Model_ID LIKE '%Z5__';
```

> two underscore for hundred and 3 underscore for thousand